# anything wrong with using a solid state relay to trigger a magnetic relay?

Tags: mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPxA1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm thinking to use a MOSFET solid state relay triggered by a MCU to trigger a micro magnetic relay.

I will be using a sufficiently rated flyback diode at the magnetic relay.

This doesn't seem to be commonly done. My reason is that high current solid state relays are way more costly than a low current SSR and a micro magnetic relay together.

Is there any reason to not do this?

EDIT - added schematic

Comment: If it's not commonly done then probably there's a better (simpler, cheaper) way. Draw a schematic of your proposal so that we really see what you mean.

Comment: Why do you need a Solid State Relay to turn on a micro magnetic relay? Are you building a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)?

Comment: building a what?...

Comment: The magnetic relay coil draws too much current for the MCU output to control it directly.

Comment: Why the trouble of an SSR? Why not just a MOSFET to turn on the coil for the relay?

Comment: IDK... I guess because I'm new at this and this was the first solution to come to mind. Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Simply substitute a suitable N-channel MOSFET for the solid state relay. Look for a suitably low Vgs(on). You might want to use a current limiting resistor between the MCU and the gate.

Comment: I nearly forgot, remember to connect the Drain of the MOSFET to the negative side of the relay coil instead of the Source being connected to the positive side of the relay coil. Otherwise the Vgs(on) threshold will move all over the place as the voltage over the coil changes. Alternatively, if you prefer to keep the wiring as it is, you could use a p-channel MOSFET instead, but for your application using an n-channel MOSFET and swapping it around is probably the better choice.

Comment: No problem changing it, I am still in the design phase and haven't physically built anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit is fine: -

[image]

Choose a MOSFET that has a low enough gate-source threshold voltage to ensure that at the logic drive voltage, the MOSFET adequately turns on.